# using shared_ptr<T> across libs with different CRTs

Tags: c++, templates, dll, memory-management, shared-ptr

I am writing a library that includes an interface to return\receive `shared_ptr` objects.

Everything seemed just dandy until I was reminded that an application using my library could have a different CRT version as well as STL version.

this begs two questions:

1. if STL versions differ between my .lib and the app using it, how can I make sure the same version of `shared_ptr` is being used across my lib and app? (STL doesn't provide binary compatibility)
2. let's say I solved question 1 by copying STL's header defining `shared_ptr` and renaming it to `my_shared_ptr` or in any way that now gives me the same `shared_ptr` implementation across my lib and the app.
   since this is a template class, and CRT versions differ, how can I make sure a `new` has the matching `delete`?
   If my lib compiles `my_shared_ptr<SomeClass>` and the app compiles `my_shared_ptr<SomeClass>`, each compilation sticks in its own `new` and `delete` according to the CRT version.
   Now when I create and hand a `shared_ptr` from the app to my lib to destroy when done with it, mismatching `new` and `delete` might be called.

Am I right to assume two instantiations of `my_shared_ptr<SomeClass>` are to be compiled, one by the .lib and one by the app?

Thanks for any help,
Leo

Comment: `shared_ptr` has nothing to do with the STL.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you cannot easily do this, though you could conceivably create a binary-compatible shared smart pointer class, e.g. on Microsoft platforms using COM objects.  You still have to make sure that allocation and deallocation both happen in the same DLL.  This will mean replacing "new" and "delete" of your smart pointer class will calls into functions exported from your DLL that are guaranteed to call the correct new and delete implementations.

Comment: Do you happen to know what happens if both the lib and the app use `my_shared_ptr<SomeClass>`. is this class instantiated twice? once, if so where, lib or app?

Comment: @Leo.  The class is instantiated twice.  This could really surprise you if you have static members anywhere in such a class:  you will have two instances of the static member, one in the app and one in the DLL (this can also happen if both the app and dll link to the same static library).

Comment: Thanks, is this dictated by some c++ standard? Can you refer me to any kind of such standard?

Comment: Moreover, If this is the case, I can solve the matching new and delete problem. A shared_ptr points to a ref-count block with virtual member delete(). this block would be carried from the app to the lib and the proper virtual method containing the matching `delete` would be called eventually, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Leo - the "standard" that dictates this is the C++ compilation model for templates.  A template definition cannot be "linked", it has to be compiled, thus two projects compiled separately will each have their own instantiation (which may be binary compatible or not)

Comment: @Leo - if the implementation of the virtual method is compiled from within the app you are still in trouble.  The smart pointer has to call into a non-template class exported from the DLL.  This class could be your custom smart pointer class itself.

Comment: couldn't the linker look for an already instantiated `shared_ptr<A>` in the given lib and then use that same code(the lib did compile it)?